# How to restrict typescript union to values satisfying a template string

Tags: typescript

How can I restrict the union to be only the elements starting with `user`?

```
type options =
    | "user"
    | "user_ID"
    | "user_active"
    | "location"
    | "location_address";
```

I was thinking `` options extends `user${infer T}` ? options : never `` but of course, this applies to the union as a whole and not the individual elements in the union.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA9mwEsYDsDOUC8AoKuoB8oAiAV1QgCcic9DTyKB9ASQBFq8DizLGBDAMaIAbhA61iAGxgC+iFONx1ps+cn4ATDRQipURANxYsoSFACqDAPLwkaTLFsp0EAB7AIyDegAGPCgAkAN4IyABmlFAAKgC+PlAA-I5q6ABcUMgQohRGQA)

Comment: Extract<options, \`user${string}\`>

Comment: Please provide a [mre] with valid code; if those are string literal types they should be quoted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reword this as "getting all members of `options` that are assignable to `` `user${string}` ``", and luckily for us, there is a built-in utility to do this: [`Extract<T, U>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttype-union).

> Constructs a type by extracting from `T` all union members that are assignable to `U`.

That means you could write your user options as

```
type UserOptions = Extract<options, `user${string}`>;
```

and that'll get all members in `options` that start with "user".

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA9mwEsYDsDOUC8AoKuoB8oAiAV1QgCcic9DTyKB9ASQBFq8DizLGBDAMaIAbhA61iAGxgC+iFONx1ps+cn4ATDRQipURANxYsoSFACqDAPLwkaTFACiAD2AVBwADxw1qADRQAAY8FAAkAN6obgjIAOYAvoEAfEYA9Kl4AHoA-EA)

---

You may notice that `Extract` is basically doing what you're doing. "Hey, why doesn't *my* code work?" That's due to [distributive conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types). In `Extract`, it's a naked generic type parameter, so if it's a union, it gets **distributed**. With your original code, it's not a naked generic type parameter, so it's not distributed.

One way you could trigger distribution is by making it a generic type parameter and having it default to `options`. It'd work the same as `Extract` under the hood.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA9mwEsYDsDOUC8AoKuoB8oAiAV1QgCcic9DTyKB9ASQBFq8DizLGBDAMaIAbhA61iAGxgC+iFONx1ps+cn4ATDRQipURANxYsoSFACqDAPLwkaADxXMsWylQA+Z04gAPYBGQNdAADHgoAEgBvBGQAM0ooABUAX2CoAH4oJwAuKGQIUQojE3BoAA1nS0obNVQjAHp6vAA9dKA)